# video conversion, hdmi to vga switch to computer capture

Tags: video-capture

I am trying to figure out the best way to go from a hdmi from a camcorder and a vga from a computer that both go to a switch then the  output is vga and i need to go to a composite dvd recorder and i also need to capture it on a computer?
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If your asking can you go from a hdmi to a vga, you can only do it with a signal converter as one is Analog and one is Digital.

If your not asking that then you need to be a lot more specific and clear with your questions.